# How to HTML Content bind in Iframe using MVC razor view?

Tags: model-view-controller, iframe

### Create TestModel class in the project show below code.

```
  public class TestModel
    {
        public long EmailTemplateId { get; set; }
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public string TemplateContent { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsDefaultTemplate { get; set; }
        public string TemplateKey { get; set; }
        public string TemplatePath { get; set; }
        public string TemplateJson { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> IsAdmin { get; set; }
        public int TemplateType { get; set; }
        public string TemplateTag { get; set; }
}
```

### Create GetTestlst action method to the controller and get all data and list pass test.cshtml

```
 public ActionResult GetTestlst()
        {
            var templist = GetTestList().ToList();
            return View(templist);
        }
```

---

below code written Test.cshtml page and get the model list in controller to view.

```
@using test.Helpers;
@model List<test.Entities.TestModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Template";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].EmailTemplateId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].TemplateName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].TemplateContent)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].CreatedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].UpdatedDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].IsDefaultTemplate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].TemplateKey)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].TemplatePath)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].TemplateJson)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].IsAdmin)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].TemplateType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].TemplateTag)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailTemplateId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TemplateName)

            </td>
            <td>


**`<iframe id="testiframe" class="iframe" src=@item.TemplateContent></iframe>`**

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
            </td>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.UpdatedDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.IsDefaultTemplate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TemplateKey)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TemplatePath)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Raw(item.TemplateJson)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.IsAdmin)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TemplateType)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.TemplateTag)
            </th>
            <td>
                @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Test", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "Test", new { id = item.Id }, null) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Test", new { id = item.Id }, null)*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Show output below image.
Iframe proper but not show Html content in the model list. please give the answer.

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Old Code replace to below code

```
<iframe id="testiframe" class="iframe" src=@item.TemplateContent></iframe>
```

I solved this issue

```
<div id=@item.EmailTemplateId style="height:200px; overflow:scroll;">@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.TemplateContent))</div>
```

Comment: ```Answer working properly but not use in iframe using div section.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered loading the HTML into a container?

```
<div id='@item.EmailTemplateId'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#@item.EmailTemplateId').load('@item.'); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for answering me but I want to show in iframe.i have using  @foreach loop in view then not working for me

Comment: It should be possible using in a loop, since we give the container the id from the Model. So it is unique for every line.